# Grep stops suddenly

Tags: python, grep, subprocess, popen

I am trying to parse a file in Python, using grep but it always stops at the same line and I am enable to understand why. I tried three different ways :

```
process = os.popen("grep -A1 "+name+" "+new_hairpins+" | grep -oE '.{0,6}"+seq+".{0,6}'")
results = process.readlines()
process.close()
```

then

```
process = subprocess.Popen("grep -A1 "+name+" "+new_hairpins+" | grep -oE '.{0,6}"+seq+".{0,6}'",stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE, shell=True)
process.wait()
process_result = process.communicate()
results = filter(None, process_result[0].split("\n"))
```

and through a temp file

```
os.system("grep -A1 "+name+" "+new_hairpins+" | grep -oE '.{0,6}"+seq+".{0,6}' > tmp.txt")
with open("tmp.txt","r") as f :
    results = f.readlines()
```

but the script always fails at the same line.
I manually tried this line directly in bash, and it worked....!

So could it be a memory issue from grep and how could I fix this problem ?
Thanks a lot !

Comment: Why are you calling `grep` as a subprocess? Python is perfectly capable of comparing the lines in a file against a regex without using external processes.

Comment: Have you considered parsing the file in python rather than calling an external tool to do the job for you?

Comment: I did it like this because it's faster for me to use 2 grep than writing lines of code to do the same thing. Further more, grep is yet optimal so my redoing same thing? Of course, if there is no solution to my problem I will have to do in python...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found the problem : my fault !

I realized that the file new_hairpins I used in the grep and that I generated just before in the code wasn't closed with .close()....

As it was working on the 1879 first lines, I didn't think the problem could come from this file...

Anyway, thanks for your help guys!

Answer (score 2):

You need to quote command line argument because there's a space in between:

```
"grep -A1 '"+name+" "+new_hairpins+"' | grep ....
          ^                         ^
```

Otherwise, `name`, `new_hairpins` will be treated as separated arguments.

Comment: new_hairpins is the file and name is the term to search, so I don't think quotes are the solution... Furthermore, it's working very well on the 1879 first lines and stops at the 1880th.....

Comment: @spacup, Could you update the question with full traceback you got?

Comment: I don't have any traceback... Just the results variable is empty.

Comment: But I repeat : when I use the exactly same command on 1880th line and followings in bash, it works !

Comment: I just realize that in my tmp.txt file, sometimes there are lines only containing 2 dashes -- I don't know why they appear... maybe it could be the origine of the problem ?

Comment: They are group separator, can be deleted with sed '/^--$/d' but, it doesn't change anything...